# low-quality answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I get that answering on Philosophy SE doesn't require a degree, but shouldn't the answers be at least slightly academic?

I won't link the question here because it could be considered a conflict of interest (since I answered it), but every other answer i saw was nothing but what the respective authors percieved the issue to be, and all of the answers were devoid ig any familiarity with the discipline. Seriously, its quite sad.

However, That is still not as bad as what I saw a couple of weeks ago: I read one of the most "senseless" strings of sentences which the answerer tried to pass as a formal proof. Regardless, I think there should be a min threshold for some questions (especially those that are pertinent to philosophy as an academic discipline).

-Pardon the typos

Answer (score 3):

That’s why the scoring system, edits, flags etc. exist.   They are the mechanism to manage content quality.  These are the tools we have to improve the quality of the site.

Comment: Downvotes alone won't push a post to moderators to review. Use flags if there's a problem other than lacking factual correctness.